# Fatal Error on Aviary Options Add-On for Gravity Forms Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have installed the Gravity Forms on my admin panel and I am trying to add the Aviary Add-On for photo editing.

When I Activate the Aviary plugin I see the Aviary Options tab but when I click I see this error:

> **Fatal error:** Cannot redeclare options_discussion_add_js() (previously declared in
>   /nfs/c09/h04/mnt/138726/domains/fotobllok.com/html/wp-admin/includes/options.php:26)
>   in
>   /nfs/c09/h04/mnt/138726/domains/fotobllok.com/html/wp-admin/includes/options.php
>   on line 27

I have restored my theme twice but to no results. Also, I have disabled all my others plugins leaving only the Gravity Form and Aviary Add-on activated but the problem persists.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after hours of research I carefully read the options.php file. The file stated that it is @wordpress since 4.4.0 version.

I just installed the 4.3 version of WordPress and everything seems to work.